# dynamic changing Link button class Attribute is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please help me in the below problem, I am still new to vb.net and I need to change the class of the clicked link button dynamically.

the ASP code is :

```
 <asp:Panel ID ="Panel2" runat="server" >
                  <div class="topnav">
                      <asp:LinkButton  ID="cat3" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/MiBundlesV2.aspx?cat=3" >Bundles1</asp:LinkButton>
                      <asp:LinkButton  ID="cat1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/MiBundlesV2.aspx?cat=1" >Bundles2</asp:LinkButton>

                  </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

I have to change this class attribute every page_init

```
 Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

       Dim catid As String = Request.QueryString("cat")

        If catid Is Nothing Then
            catid = 3
        End If

 Dim lnkBut As New LinkButton
 Dim Idcat As String = "cat" & catid
 lnkBut = DirectCast(Panel2.FindControl(Idcat), LinkButton)
 lnkBut.Attributes("class") = "active"
```

I have this error returned 
in order to evaluate an indexed property the property must be qualified

Answer (score 0):

The exception you wrote maybe is not around attribute setting.
However to set a css class you can use this instead:

```
If lnkBut IsNot Nothing Then
    lnkBut.CssClass = "active"
End If
```